# Set Azure Reserved IP on cloud service via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

as said in the title, I can't assign an IP to my cloud service.

I've followed a lot of forums and StackOverflow articles/posts but I've still the issue.

When I try to run

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName primosguardo365reservedip -ServiceName primosguardo365
```

I get this error

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName primosguardo365reserve ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.SetAzureReservedIPAssociationCmdlet
```

but if I try to get the resources using the same name

```
λ  Get-AzureReservedIP

ReservedIPName       : Group Primosguardo365 primosguardo365reservedip
Address              : **.**.**.**
Id                   : ******************
Label                :
Location             : West Europe
State                : Created
InUse                : False
ServiceName          :
DeploymentName       :
VirtualIPName        :
OperationDescription : Get-AzureReservedIP
OperationId          : ************************
OperationStatus      : Succeeded


λ  Get-AzureService "primosguardo365"

ServiceName             : primosguardo365
Url                     : https://management.core.windows.net.................
Label                   : primosguardo365
Description             : primosguardo365
Location                : West Europe
AffinityGroup           :
Status                  : Created
ExtendedProperties      : {[ResourceGroup, Primosguardo365], [ResourceLocation, westeurope], [ProvisioningSource,
                          AzureResourceManager]}
DateModified            : 28/03/2017 12:13:20
DateCreated             : 28/03/2017 11:26:03
ReverseDnsFqdn          :
WebWorkerRoleSizes      : {}
VirtualMachineRoleSizes : {}
OperationDescription    : Get-AzureService
OperationId             : ****************************
OperationStatus         : Succeeded
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT:***

VIP can only be assigned to a deployed **PRODUCTION** instance.

But that's useless, cause CloudServices already have static IP.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Is the cloud service deployed?

Comment: yes, I've tested it and it's working! but I still have the issue!

Comment: Edited the question, I've managed to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, I reproduce your error, I just create a cloud service via **new portal**, and then associate a reserved IP address to it, the error occur.

```
PS C:\Users> Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName my9 -ServiceName "jasontest323"
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName my9 -ServiceName "jaso ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.SetAzureReservedIPAssociationCmdlet
```

After that, I create another cloud service and a VM, then assiscate a reserved IP address to this cloud service, it works.

```
PS C:\Users> Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName my9 -ServiceName "jasonvm3659"

OperationDescription           OperationId                          OperationStatus
--------------------           -----------                          ---------------
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation 05ccff35-5642-7cc6-9c6b-b5dfe2d1603d Succeeded
```

So, I check the status of the two cloud service, I find when the Production is running, the command will work.
[image]

[image]

We can use PowerShell to check the deployment:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName jasontest323
Get-AzureDeployment : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.
OperationID : '27da300bc3c67a5bbdbc954c1c19e3e7'
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName jasontest323
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureDeployment], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.GetAzureDeploymentCommand

PS C:\Users> Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName jasonvm3659


SdkVersion                :
RollbackAllowed           : False
Slot                      : Production
Name                      : jasonvm3659
DeploymentName            : jasonvm3659
Url                       : http://jasonvm3659.cloudapp.net/
Status                    : Running
CurrentUpgradeDomain      : 0
CurrentUpgradeDomainState :
UpgradeType               :
RoleInstanceList          : {jasonvm}
Configuration             : <ServiceConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration">
                              <Role name="jasonvm">
                                <Instances count="1" />
                              </Role>
                            </ServiceConfiguration>
DeploymentId              : fc627acb502a4a979b08c42f69cccf72
Label                     : jasonvm3659
VNetName                  : Group jasontest321 jasontest321
DnsSettings               :
OSVersion                 :
RolesConfiguration        : {[jasonvm, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.RoleConfiguration]}
VirtualIPs                : {jasonvm3659ContractContract}
ReservedIPName            : my9
CreatedTime               : 3/29/2017 1:10:28 PM
LastModifiedTime          : 3/29/2017 1:27:42 PM
Locked                    : False
InternalLoadBalancerName  :
LoadBalancers             : {}
ExtensionConfiguration    :
ServiceName               : jasonvm3659
OperationDescription      : Get-AzureDeployment
OperationId               : f8b8xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx2cdc1daa
OperationStatus           : Succeeded
```

The reserved IPs work for classic module, only be used for **VMs** and **cloud service instance roles** exposed through a VIP.

So we should check the deployment with powershell `Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName primosguardo365`  first.